# Elasticsearch Service Running but Status "Not Running"

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm running Elasticsearch 1.4.4 on Ubuntu. When I attempt to start Elasticsearch as a service then check its status via `service elasticsearch status`, it appears that the service is "not running". However, when I check the cluster and various running processes, Elasticsearch appears to be up and running:

```
root     13353 36.7  1.9 3241608 315276 pts/1  Sl   10:30   0:09 /usr/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Xss256k -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Delasticsearch -Des.pidfile=-Des.config=/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml -Des.path.home=/elasticsearch -cp :/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch.jar:/elasticsearch/lib/*:/elasticsearch/lib/sigar/* -Des.path.home=/elasticsearch -Des.path.logs=/elasticsearch/logs -Des.path.data=/elasticsearch/data -Des.path.work= org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch
```

My init.d looks like this:

```
    PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/elasticsearch/bin
    DESC="Elasticsearch"
    NAME=elasticsearch
    ES_HOME=/elasticsearch
    ES_MIN_MEM=256m
    ES_MAX_MEM=2g
    DAEMON=$ES_HOME/bin/$NAME
    LOG_DIR=$ES_HOME/logs
    DATA_DIR=$ES_HOME/data
    CONFIG_FILE=$ES_HOME/config/elasticsearch.yml
    PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
    SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME
    DAEMON_ARGS="-p $PID_FILE -Des.config=$CONFIG_FILE -Des.path.home=$ES_HOME -Des.path.logs=$LOG_DIR -Des.path.data=$DATA_DIR -Des.path.work=$WORK_DIR -d"

    # Exit if the package is not installed
    [ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

    # Read configuration variable file if it is present
    [ -r /etc/default/$NAME ] && . /etc/default/$NAME

    # Load the VERBOSE setting and other rcS variables
    . /lib/init/vars.sh

    # Define LSB log_* functions.
    # Depend on lsb-base (>= 3.2-14) to ensure that this file is present
    # and status_of_proc is working.
    . /lib/lsb/init-functions

    #
    # Function that starts the daemon/service
    #
    do_start()
    {
            # Return
            #   0 if daemon has been started
            #   1 if daemon was already running
            #   2 if daemon could not be started
            start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON --test > /dev/null \
                    || return 1
            start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON \
                    -- $DAEMON_ARGS \
                    || return 2
            # Add code here, if necessary, that waits for the process to be ready
            # to handle requests from services started subsequently which depend
            # on this one.  As a last resort, sleep for some time.
    }

    ...

case "$1" in
  start)
        [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
        do_start
        case "$?" in
                0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
                2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
        esac
        ;;
  stop)
        [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"
        do_stop
        case "$?" in
                0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
                2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
        esac
        ;;
  status)
        status_of_proc "$DAEMON" "$NAME" && exit 0 || exit $?
        ;;
  #reload|force-reload)
        #
        # If do_reload() is not implemented then leave this commented out
        # and leave 'force-reload' as an alias for 'restart'.
        #
        #log_daemon_msg "Reloading $DESC" "$NAME"
        #do_reload
        #log_end_msg $?
        #;;
  restart|force-reload)
        #
        # If the "reload" option is implemented then remove the
        # 'force-reload' alias
        #
        log_daemon_msg "Restarting $DESC" "$NAME"
        do_stop
        case "$?" in
          0|1)
                do_start
                case "$?" in
                        0) log_end_msg 0 ;;
                        1) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Old process is still running
                        *) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Failed to start
                esac
                ;;
          *)
                # Failed to stop
                log_end_msg 1
                ;;
        esac
        ;;
  *)
        #echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload}" >&2
        echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|status|restart|force-reload}" >&2
        exit 3
        ;;
esac
:
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You did nothing wrong, but it might be that you don't have `status_of_proc`  installed. What do you see if you try to simply run `status_of_proc` in your shell?

Comment: There you go, then that's why you see that the service is not running, even though it is. What version of Ubuntu are you running on?

Comment: 14.04 - but, I'm not sure that's the reason. I don't have the same problem with other services that I've created. service [name] status on any other service and I have no problem.